# sequence over colors in R

Tags: r, colors, color-picker, color-palette

Is there a way to create a sequence over colors in R?

for example, anything like:

```
 seq("#000000", "#999999", length=20)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See `colorRampPalette` and the related `colorRamp` function.

```
palette <- colorRampPalette(colors=c("#000000", "#FFFFFF"))
cols <- palette(20)
plot(1:20, col=cols, pch=16, cex=3)
```

[image]

For some other interesting options, check out the **colorspace** package, loading it and then doing `example(rainbow_hcl)` and then, if you're intrigued by what you see, `vignette("hcl-colors")`.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta -- Always especially glad to help folks who are helping others in turn! Cheers.